# Kendo numerictextbox was clicked up or down

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendonumerictextbox

Can I know in which direction was clicked numerictextbox - up or down?

```
                    $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoNumericTextBox({
                        min: 1,
                        max: 9,
                        decimals: 1,
                        format: "n0",
                        value: 1,
                        spin: function(el) {
                                var count = this.value(),
                                    model = options.model;
                                model.set("quantity", count);
                                addCharacteristic(count);
                                setPrice(e, count, model);
                        }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know there is no default mechanizm in `kendo` to do this.

`NumericTextBox` have 2 [events](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/events) `change` and `spin` and they cant help in your case.

I think the best way to achive this is add event listeners on up/down buttons on click event of `NumericTextBox`.